# Query selector in nested AngularJS Directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I'm using two directives in this HTML code:

```
<div animations>
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <span class="animateBtn">Animate!</span>

   <info-section></info-section>
</div>
```

The first, is an Attribute Directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('animations', ['$window', ($window: any) => {
    return {
       restrict: "A",
       link: function ($scope: any, element: any, attrs: any) {
        angular.element(document).ready(() => {
            let animateBtns = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.animateBtn'));
            if (animateBtns && animateBtns.length) {
                for (let i = 0, animateBtnsLength = animateBtns.length; i < animateBtnsLength; i++) {
                    let currentBtn = animateBtns[i];
                    currentBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        .... other code....
                    });
                }
            }

              ..... other code .....

        });
       }
   };
}])
```

So, it simply does a querySelector to select all buttons that, at the click, have to start a certain function.
And it works. The problem is that the second directive  also contains an "animateBtn":

```
.directive('infoSection', function() {
   return {
       replace: true,
       restrict: 'E',
       template: '<div><span class="animateBtn">Animate with this too</span></div>'
   }
});
```

The problem is that in the first directive (even if I user (document).ready()), the selector returns just one element (the span under the title), and it doesn't include the "animateBtn" of the second directive.

Here you can find the full code: [PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZzcowjuiYO4dCtlyC22Q?p=preview)

Comment: You shouldn't try to find the other DOM elements with a querySelector. If you want to have parent-child relationships between directives, communicate between them through their controller and let the child directives provide the DOM elements they are bound to to the parent.

Comment: I added a Plunker, you can find that here: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZzcowjuiYO4dCtlyC22Q?p=preview

Comment: As Oliver already said, what you're doing is wrong. Also you should never put event handlers on code in angular like that - that's jQuery way. Try reading this, might help you figure out some better concepts for angularjs: https://gabrieleromanato.name/introduction-to-angularjs-for-jquery-developers  After you read it try recreating it in AngularJS way and maybe try using ng-animate for animating stuff in angularjs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Comment: thanks @panagulis72 I need to use angular $element rather than element  at element[0] var animateBtns = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.animateBtn')); Angularjs v1.6.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With AngularJS one uses directives to attach code to elements instead  of query selectors:

```
app.directive("animateBtn", function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on('click', function() {

             .... other code....

        });

          .... other code....

    }
})
```

The above directive will attach the click handler and associated code to each element with the class `animateBtn` when the element is added to the DOM by the AngularJS framework.

---

> if a write a function inside "animations" directive, how can I trigger it inside "animatBtn" directive? I mean, in your code, inside the first line of "..... other code...." how can I call a function written in the "animations" directive?

Use the `require` property of the DDO to access the controller of the `animations` directive:

```
app.directive("animateBtn", function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: postLink,
        require: '^animations'
    };
    function postLink (scope, elem, attrs, animations) {
        elem.on('click', function() {

             .... other code....

        });

        //call animations API

        animations.someMethod(args);

    }
})
```

In the `animations` directive:

```
app.directive("animations", function() {
    return {
        controller: ctrl
    }
    function ctrl($element, $scope) {
        this.someMethod = function(args) {
            //code here
        };
    }
})
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)

Comment: It seems a great solution! But if a write a function inside "animations" directive, how can I trigger it inside "animatBtn" directive? I mean, in your code, inside the first line of "..... other code...." how can I call a function written in the "animations" directive?

Comment: Use the `require` property of the DDO. See update to answer.